# VBA Runtime Error 1004 only on Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I have been scratching my head on this one for a while.

I'm more used to incompatibilities on 2010 with files that have been opened on 2016, but in this case, I have a Macro that works well on Office 2010 but generates a Runtime Error on Excel 2016 (which is a shame since we're supposed to migrate to Win 10 soon)

So I'm trying to figure out what the problem is.

Here is the code:

```
Sub prd_cons()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

envoyeur = "XXX - Reporting Operationnel <XxX@mail.com>"
Attachments = "C:\TEMP\" & "Productivité " & Range("NOM_CONS_PRD") & ".pdf"
Corps = "Bonjour, <br><br> "
Corps = Corps & "Vous trouverez ci-joint votre productivité "
Corps = Corps & "<br><br>Cordialement,<br>Le Support Opérationnel"

Set rng = Nothing
Set rng = Range("PRD_CONS")
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
Attachments, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

With OutMail
.To = Range("B1").Value
.Subject = "Productivité " & Range("NOM_CONS_PRD")
.HTMLBody = Corps
.Attachments.Add Attachments
.Display '.send pour envoyer directement le mail"
 End With

Kill Attachments

 Set OutMail = Nothing
 Set OutApp = Nothing
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub


Sub prd()


Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Conseillers_Mois" Then periode = " de " & Format(Range("B4").Value, "mmmm") & " " & Range("B5").Value: periode2 = periode
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Conseillers_Jour" Then periode = " du " & Range("B4").Value: periode2 = Year(Range("B4").Value) & Format(Month(Range("B4").Value), "00") & Format(Day(Range("B4").Value), "00")
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Conseillers_Semestre" Then periode = Range("B4").Value


envoyeur = "XXX <XxX@mail.com>"
Attachments = "C:\TEMP\" & "Productivité " & periode2 & ".pdf"
Corps = "Bonjour, <br><br> "
Corps = Corps & "Vous trouverez ci-joint la productivité équipe " & periode
Corps = Corps & "<br><br>Cordialement,<br>Le Support Opérationnel"

Set rng = Nothing
Set rng = Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(74, 18 + Range("N1").Value * 5))
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim plage As Range
Set plage = Range(Cells(2, 18), Cells(2, 18 + Range("N1").Value * 5))

For Each c In plage
If Len(c) > 0 Then txt = txt & c.Value & ";"
Next

For Each c In Range("CC")
If Len(c) > 0 Then txtcc = txtcc & c.Value & ";"
Next


rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
Attachments, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

With OutMail
.To = txt
.CC = txtcc
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Subject"
.HTMLBody = Corps
.Attachments.Add Attachments
.Display '.send to send e-mail directly"
 End With

Kill Attachments

 Set OutMail = Nothing
 Set OutApp = Nothing
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
 Dim ts As Object
 Dim TempFile As String

TempFile = "C:\TEMP\Temp.htm" 'create empty htm file

'paste data in the empty htm file

With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceRange, Filename:=TempFile, Sheet:="Conseillers_Jour", Source:=rng.Address, HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
.Publish (True)
End With

'rangetohtml = temp data

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
 RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
 ts.Close
 RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
"align=left x:publishsource=")

Kill TempFile 'delete temp file

Set ts = Nothing
 Set fso = Nothing

End Function

Sub test()
For Each element In Range("GRAPH1")
Debug.Print element
Next
End Sub


Sub prd2()


Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Conseillers_Mois" Then periode = " de " & Format(Range("B4").Value, "mmmm") & " " & Range("B5").Value: periode2 = periode
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Conseillers_Jour" Then periode = " du " & Range("B4").Value: periode2 = Year(Range("B4").Value) & Format(Month(Range("B4").Value), "00") & Format(Day(Range("B4").Value), "00")
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Conseillers_Semestre" Then periode = Range("B4").Value


'envoyeur = "<YyY@mail.com>"
'envoyeur = "<ZzZ@mail.com>"
envoyeur = "AaA@mail.com"
Attachments = "C:\TEMP\" & "Productivité " & periode2 & ".pdf"
Corps = "Bonjour, <br><br> "
Corps = Corps & "MESSAGE " & periode
Corps = Corps & "<br><br>Concatenated,<br>message"

Set rng = Nothing
Set rng = Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(74, 18 + Range("N1").Value * 5))
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim plage As Range
Set plage = Range(Cells(2, 18), Cells(2, 18 + Range("N1").Value * 5))

For Each c In plage
If Len(c) > 0 Then txt = txt & c.Value & ";"
Next

txtcc = ""
For Each c In Range("CC")
If Len(c) > 0 Then txtcc = txtcc & c.Value & ";"
Next
txtcc = txtcc & "YyY@mail.com" & ";"

rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
Attachments, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

With OutMail
.To = txt
.CC = txtcc
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "xxx"
.HTMLBody = Corps
.Attachments.Add Attachments
.Display
 End With

Kill Attachments

 Set OutMail = Nothing
 Set OutApp = Nothing
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```

When I run this on office 2010, I'm good but on Office I get the dreaded Runtime Error 1004, and while debugging, this is what is highlighted

```
rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
Attachments, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Any idea what would make the code incompatible wth Office 2016?

Comment: Have you tested whether a small range (say `A1:Z10`) will execute?

Comment: Check in each version's object browser for differences. If there aren't any then test each property one by one!

Comment: Have you tried using macro recorder on Excel 2016 and then manually save as PDF? Then you could compare both codes (original one, and the macro recorder one) and see if there is any difference.

Comment: I'll try each and everyone of your solutions and see what comes out of them...